# Getting the same row returned every time when I order by timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

My postgresql database keeps returning the same last row when I order by created_at (a timestamp) and limit the number of results.

The last result is always the same row. Take a look at the last id in these results:

```
looked=# select id,created_at from businesses order by created_at asc limit 2;
id |          created_at
----+-------------------------------
38 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
20 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
(2 rows)

looked=# select id,created_at from businesses order by created_at asc limit 5;
id  |          created_at
------+-------------------------------
38 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
436 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
1334 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
2845 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
20 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
(5 rows)

looked=# select id,created_at from businesses order by created_at asc limit 10;
id  |          created_at
------+-------------------------------
38 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
436 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
1334 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
2845 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
3381 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
1089 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
822 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
2310 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
1773 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
20 | 2011-04-30 18:31:23.923475+10
(10 rows)
```

Comment: The values are the same because it's my seed data, and I chose set all created_at values to NOW(). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `created_at` values are the same. The ORDER BY and LIMIT will *arbitrarily* pick rows from the set of rows where `created_at` is the lowest value

You'd have to add an extra sort condition to "tie break" these rows. Here I added `id`

```
select id,created_at from businesses
order by created_at asc, id limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each row's created_at value is identical.  Postgres is breaking the ties arbitrarily.  Add another ordering condition (such as on ID) if you want more control/predictability.